# SQL - Showing all parents from recursive relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have a table for categories. This has a recursive relationship so that a category can become a subcategory of another category. The table looks like this:

```
id  name    short_desc  long_desc   tag_id  parent_id
```

I wrote simple to get sql to find all level 1 categories:

```
 SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id =0
```

Then I wrote a query to get all of the level 2 categories (where parent category doesn't have a parent)

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM category WHERE parent_id =0)
```

What I would like to do, is produce a column where is shows all category data and any relevant parent category.

Logically like this:

1. select all from category
2. if parent_id != 0, add the parent as a new row
3. repeat 2 until all parents have been accounted for.

The result should look something like this:

```
id  name    short_desc  long_desc   tag_id   parent_name  parent_name_2
```

if the parent_name is null / empty, then parent_name should remain empty. if there is a parent_name id in the field, then check to see if there is a parent_name_2 and if so, populate both columns, if not then only populate parent_name.

I do have the option of coding this in jquery or php which I have a good idea how to do. However, I am sure that I can get the data I need from a good SQL query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Nick

Comment: If you know the number of potential levels, you can use multiple outer self joins.  If it is unknown, then you'll need to use dynamic sql.  Several examples on SO with both...

Comment: There will only ever be a maximum of 3 levels. Parent, child, grandchild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using multiple outer joins:

```
select c.*, 
  case when c2.id is not null then c2.name end parent_name,
  case when c3.id is not null then c3.name end parent_name_2
from category c
  left join category c2 on c.parent_id = c2.id
  left join category c3 on c2.parent_id = c3.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a5cce/2)

Comment: That worked exactly! Thanks for the link , never seen that before but very, VERY useful! Thanks again :)